# Fetching data error after first row

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I'm currently having problems with fetching data from a database. It's really driving me crazing, especially since it's the exact code I use for fetching other tables which work.

```
    if ($content = $database->prepare($sql_get_all_articles)){
            $content->execute();
            $content->bind_result($id, $title, $content, $author, $date_posted);

                while($content->fetch()){
                    echo "<article>
                          <h2>".$title."</h2>
                          <div class=\"article-info\">Posted on <time datetime=\"".$date_posted."\">".$date_posted."</time> by <a href=\"#\" rel=\"author\">".$author."</a></div>
                          <p>".$content."</p>
                          <a href=\"#\" class=\"button\">Read more</a>
                          <a href=\"#\" class=\"button\">Comments</a>
                          </article>";
                }

            $content->close();
        }
```

The code works once, it only posts the first article. But when trying the second one it returns the error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 47

The SQL statement I use is:

```
$sql_get_all_articles = "SELECT id, title, content, author, date_posted FROM article";
```

Comment: You are using `$content` to name both the query and one of the fields  mentioned in `bind_result()` to capture results of the query. So the first `fetch()` operation overwrites the query.

Comment: Look at my answer for a future-proof solution in this...

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($content = $database->prepare($sql_get_all_articles)){
        $content->execute();

            while($result = $content->fetchObject()){
                echo "<article>
                      <h2>".$result->title."</h2>
                      <div class=\"article-info\">Posted on <time datetime=\"".$result->date_posted."\">".$date_posted."</time> by <a href=\"#\" rel=\"author\">".$result->author."</a></div>
                      <p>".$result->content."</p>
                      <a href=\"#\" class=\"button\">Read more</a>
                      <a href=\"#\" class=\"button\">Comments</a>
                      </article>";
            }

        $content->close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `$content` to name both the query and one of the fields mentioned in `bind_result()` to capture results of the query. So the first `fetch()` operation overwrites the query.